# Owasp ZAP not performing authentication during active scan using "Form-Based-Authentication" ON python project

Tags: security, docker, owasp, zap

I am facing roadblock on a owasp zap form based authentication. I setup zap property as per guidance. When i run active scan then "when to attempt login it give FORBIDDEN error. CSRF token not available.

Owasp ZAP not performing authentication during active scan using "Form-Based-Authentication" ON python project.

[[image: here is my zap screen]
My target url is:

```
http://example.com:84/admin/login/?next=/admin/
```

Post data ;

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken=IjYwHHavnCYgcWYMy2oL3L9Z0ldUH95s&username={%username%}&password={%password%}&next=%2Fadmin%2F
```

here is the html response i got:

```
<div id="summary">
  <h1>Forbidden <span>(403)</span></h1>
  <p>CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.</p>


</div>

<div id="info">
  <h2>Help</h2>

    <p>Reason given for failure:</p>
    <pre>
    CSRF token missing or incorrect.
    </pre>


  <p>In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when
  <a
  href="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/">Django's
  CSRF mechanism</a> has not been used correctly.  For POST forms, you need to
  ensure:</p>

  <ul>
    <li>Your browser is accepting cookies.</li>

    <li>The view function passes a <code>request</code> to the template's <a
    href="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.base.Template.render"><code>render</code></a>
    method.</li>

    <li>In the template, there is a <code>{% csrf_token
    %}</code> template tag inside each POST form that
    targets an internal URL.</li>

    <li>If you are not using <code>CsrfViewMiddleware</code>, then you must use
    <code>csrf_protect</code> on any views that use the <code>csrf_token</code>
    template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.</li>

  </ul>

  <p>You're seeing the help section of this page because you have <code>DEBUG =
  True</code> in your Django settings file. Change that to <code>False</code>,
  and only the initial error message will be displayed.  </p>

  <p>You can customize this page using the CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW setting.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunatley ZAP doesnt currently support the automatic regeneration of CSRF tokens when authenticating.

A way around this is to record a Zest authentication script - make sure that you start by requesting the page token that generates that token.

Recording Zest scripts is covered in this FAQ (which is otherwise unrelated): https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQreportFN

Feel free to hassle us about supporting ACSR toeksn when authenticating on https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users :)

Answer (score 2):

I know this have been asked for almost 7 Years now, but for those who are struggling with this -like me- you should use this script https://github.com/zaproxy/community-scripts/blob/main/authentication/DjangoAuthentication.js

1- Load script into Zap, I couldn't add it through marketplace, so I had to manually download it from the repo and load it through the tools/options/script menu

2- add it as an authentication method for the context you are using